# How to duplicate blockuserinfo module or inherite of it

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i would like to add an access for professional users on my web site. i am able to duplicate the blockuserinfo and install it in the displayNav hook.
I would like to display a different content text for the page index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account.
What template should i need to update ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

youtheme/my-account.tpl

Regards

Comment: sorry i found it in the previous page : authentication.tpl but i would like to have 2 differents pages for authentication : normal user and professional user. thanks